# Tsql Null value missing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, uniqueidentifier

When I run the following script, I get the Null value in the first query but not in the second.  How can I still include the Null value in the second query while excluding this one uniqueidentifier value?

```
drop table program_field

create table program_field
(p  uniqueidentifier
)

insert program_field values ('10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005'),
('16BD98AA-2323-4619-8BAF-0C19F90642FF'),
(Null)

select  p from program_field
select  p from program_field where p <> '10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005'
```

Comment: NULL <> '10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005' is a FALSE statement, so your 2nd query doesn't return it.  NULL is not less than, greater than or equal to anything, ever.  That's why you need to do a separate comparison for the NULL condition as described in the answers already provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  p from program_field where p <> '10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005' or p is null
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` expressions in `where clause` to compare to `null` values Like :

`p <> '10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005' or p is null`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this..

```
select  p from program_field where coalesce(p,'') <> '10C8BCA5-011C-48B9-BF46-03B88EBF5005'
```

Comment: This will give conversion error. Wont be able to cast empty string to unique identifier.

Comment: You could replace the ISNULL with COALESCE to get it to work.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal : Oops! didnt completely read the question.Updated now!